# I have website i downloaded all files on the server but i couldn't find the sores code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**I have a big problem i started with the company and they asked me to add and delete some thing from our website but i couldn't fine any code i used VB.NET and ASP.NET, please any help how to find the code, Thank you.

Comment: Take help of your Lead and Manager. :)

Comment: Can't you ask someone where the source code is stored?

Comment: It may be the build(published files) only.

Answer (score 1):

In most ASP.NET web sites, non-updateable files are just pointer files and do not have any actual code. Your code has been compiled into a DLL in the BIN folder of your website.  While I am sure someone here will tell you how to disassemble the DLL, my answer is that you must get the original code (not from the web site) that was used to make the web site.

If no one there knows where this code is, try doing some searches on the network (or previous employees computer that might have built the web site) for some of the file names you found on the web site.

If you can't find the source. Start over.